# Harmonic functions with conditions on $u$, $\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}$ on the boundary

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, boundary-value-problem

Let $\Omega$ be an open and bounded domain with boundary $\partial\Omega_1 \cup \partial\Omega_2 = \partial\Omega$.

Does there exist a $C^2$-function $u$ such that

$$ \begin{cases} \Delta u = 0 & \text{ in } \Omega, \\
u = 0, & \text{ on } \partial \Omega_1 \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}= h>0  & \text{ on } \partial \Omega_2?\end{cases} 
$$

Comment: In the partial derivative on the third line, what is $n$?

Comment: It is a normal vector, so du/dn is a derivative in the normal direction.